# Ionic navigate from one page to another, not working

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, routes, navigation

I'm having the following issue. I created an ionic projekt and generated a Homepage and a Register page.
When I try to do the navigation from home to register, and when I click on the register button it brings me back to homepage, instead of going to register page. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I read bassicaly everything I found, and it seems that I am doing everything correctly. I also tried with a href, but I still have the same problem.

Here is the button that i generated in my Homepage html:

```
   <ion-button (click)="register()">Register</ion-button>
```

Here is the Funktion in ts-file:

```
      register() {
      this.navctrl.navigateForward(['register']);
      }
```

And here is the auto generated path in the routing page:

```
{ path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/.module#RegisterPageModule' },
```

Comment: use "Router" from '@angular/router' for navigation.following is sample code -

this.router.navigate(['/register']);

Comment: You can have more idea about the difference between Navcontroller and Router https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-navigation-navcontroller-or-router/146728/2

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...
constructor(private router: Router){}
 register() {
      this.router.navigate(['/register']);
      }
```

Here you go.